# NUMPY: select even lines, last column

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to learn numpy and I can't manage to complete this question: take the even lines, last column of the M matrix:

```
 [[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25]
 [26 27 28 29 30]]
```

What I did : `print(M[0:, -1, 2], '\n')`
error: `IndexError: too many indices for array`

Why isn't this working ? I select all the lines with 0:, the last column with -1, with step 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is 2-dimensional, but you're using three indices as if your array had 3 dimensions, you can use this index to get what you want:

```
print(M[::2, -1])
```

Output:

```
[ 5 15 25]
```

Comment: great, could you explain why you put two ::

Comment: what if the question was print all the odd lines, last column ? I can't find it out.

Comment: @catrev In Python, indexing is in the form `start:stop:step`, if you omit `start`, it is assumed to be `0`, if you omit `stop`, it is assumed to be the position of the last element, if you omit `step`, it assumed to be `1`, in the answer I wrote `::2`, I omitted the start and the stop parameters, so Python will assume that I will start from `0` to the `"end"` of the array.

Comment: @catrev For odd lines, use `1::2` (start from `1`, stop at the `"end"`, and step by `2`).

Comment: Why are there two ::, I would just have put 1:-1:2 ?

Comment: @catrev The thing here is that Python doesn't include the `stop` index, it will stop at `stop - 1`, so if you write `1:-1:2`, it will stop at `-1 - 1`, which is `-2`, which the is index of the next-to-last element, so it will not even reach the last element of the array.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, awesome